# revolution jquery slider work with angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

There is someone who knows how to connect jquery revolution slider with angular js. I am running revolution slider in controller and everything is fine but there is error when i change page. I have got :

```
TypeError: r is undefined
```

I try pause slider when i change site, so i add some code :

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
            function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){             
                if (toState.name !== 'home') {
                    console.log("slider pause -->")
                    $('.slider-banner-container .slider-banner').revpause();
                } else {
                    $('.slider-banner-container .slider-banner').revresume();
                }

            })
```

But its not working, i think that there is a problem because i change a page to another and the slider is not exist on another site.

Any solutions ? Thanks